# Using HMAC-SHA256 Authentication for WCF with HttpModule

Tags: wcf, hmac

I'm trying to do HMAC-SHA256 authentication for my WCF webservices.

After much reading about HMAC-SHA on the web, I started to apply them into my project.

Now that I've successfully encrypt the message on the client-side, but how do I go about authenticating the request before the request entering the WebMethods?

I suppose I should add a HttpModule to tap into the Init() event and do validation there?

But as soon as I added the HttpModule to my WCF project and configure the web.config, I'm getting error saying:

```
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:61884/MyService.svc.
This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.
This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down).
See server logs for more details.
```

Am I right about using HttpModule in this context?

My web.config, just in-case

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpModules>
        <add name="HttpAuthenticationModule" type="WcfService.HttpAuthenticationModule" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Your web.config is missing everything to do with WCF. See if you can connect to a normal webpage on the server.

Comment: The WCF is fine. If I take out the httpModules from the web.config it works OK. I excluded the ServiceModel part here because the web.config is on another computer now, which I can't copy/paste, and it would be crazy for me to re-type them here. I should have mentioned that. My bad =)

Comment: Could you add the code listing for `HttpAuthenticationModule`?

Comment: @Aron there's nothing in the HttpAuthenticationModule, I just added it into the project without any real implementation. I put a breakpoint at Init() within the module to see if module is being called, but the error happen before it hits the breakpoint =/

Comment: Ah...right...is there an implementation though? During the early stages of the lifecycle of an app I find the debugger doesn't always work as expected. For example I've never been able to break on `Global.Init()`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that HttpModule doesn't work for self-hosted WCF services that launched from VisualStudio. After I host the WCF service in IIS, HttpModule is hitting breakpoint at BeginRequest() as what I expected now.

Hope this helps those who face the same problem.